# jaxb with Jersey inside OSGI java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jaxb, jersey, osgi, jax-rs, aem

I'm running Jersey and JaxB as a cq5 osgi bundle. Jersey works find but the problem occures when Jaxb tries to convert java object into xml. Here is my code

Jersey Class (reachable)

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public EmailNotification getNotificationInXML() throws JAXBException {


        EmailNotification emailNotification = new EmailNotification();
        emailNotification.setBody("Hello Im the body, what is yours");
        emailNotification.setAuthor_name("my name");
        emailNotification.setEmail_notification(true);
        emailNotification.setParent_identifier("XXYZ");

        return emailNotification;
```

---

Email Notification Class

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "emailNotification")
public class EmailNotification {
```

---

the code breaks on "`return emailNotification;`" with error

---

```
/emailNotification HTTP/1.1] servletengine Servlet threw exception:  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.handleClassCastException(ContextFinder.java:95)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:231)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:215)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:414)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:618)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:565)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getStoredJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:194)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getJAXBContext(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:187)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:144)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:151)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.write(ContainerResponse.java:306)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1448)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:42)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:179)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:238)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.osgi.JaxRsFilter.doFilter(JaxRsFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:48)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:39)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.service(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:250)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.doFilter(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:321)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:340)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:383)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletHandlerImpl.process(ServletHandlerImpl.java:351)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:625)
***
```

Comment: Tried ClassLoader tccl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
try {
  // execute 3rd party code
} finally {
  Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(tccl);
}
 from

Comment: Is there a way to get a reference to the Bundle class loader. In equinox its Platform.getBundle("mybundleid").getClassLoader() it sounds like a class loading issue given that each bundle has its own class loader. Not sure if that helps.